# What spoke brand is this?

Tags: spokes

This seems to be the only decent spoke brand resource on the web... http://www.mrrabbit.net/docs/spokeheads/main.html, but even it doesn't seem to have this brand, unless I just don't see it. Can anyone identify this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're e*thirteen. I don't know whether it's just a replacement/stock spoke on an e*thirteen/Hive wheel or if they were selling general purpose spoke packs for a while.

[image: picture of bicycle spokes]

[image: close-up picture of bicycle spokes]

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea they made their own spokes.